# Bash: find | sed | xargs rm not working, but rm does

Tags: bash, sed, scripting, xargs

I'm trying to remove all `.js` and `.js.map` files from any sub-directory of `src` called `__tests__`.

```bash
$ find . -path './src/**' -name __tests__ | # find subdirectories
> sed -E 's/([^ ]+__tests__)/\1\/*.js \1\/*.js.map/g' | # for each subdirectory, concat *.js and *.js.map
> xargs rm # remove files
```

This fails with the following errors:

```
rm: cannot remove './src/game/__tests__/*.js': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove './src/game/__tests__/*.js.map': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove './src/helpers/__tests__/*.js': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove './src/helpers/__tests__/*.js.map': No such file or directory
```

However, if I change my `xargs rm` to `xargs echo rm`, copy and paste the output, and run it, it works.

```bash
$ find . -path './src/**' -name __tests__ | sed -E 's/([^ ]+__tests__)/\1\/*.js \1\/*.js.map/g' |
> xargs echo rm # echo command to remove files
rm ./src/game/__tests__/*.js ./src/game/__tests__/*.js.map ./src/helpers/__tests__/*.js ./src/helpers/__tests__/*.js.map

$ rm ./src/game/__tests__/*.js ./src/game/__tests__/*.js.map ./src/helpers/__tests__/*.js ./src/helpers/__tests__/*.js.map
```

Wrapping the output of my echo in `$(...)` and prepending `rm` results in the same error as before.

```bash
$ rm $(find . -path './src/**' -name __tests__ | sed -E 's/([^ ]+__tests__)/\1\/*.js \1\/*.js.map/g' | xargs echo rm
rm: cannot remove './src/game/__tests__/*.js': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove './src/game/__tests__/*.js.map': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove './src/helpers/__tests__/*.js': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove './src/helpers/__tests__/*.js.map': No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

I doubt it matters, but I'm using GitBash on Windows.

Comment: You're telling `rm` to remove a file literally called `*.js`.

Comment: Oh, how do I remove the `''` around it?

Comment: There are no `''` around it; there's nothing to remove.

Comment: `**` isn't necessary: only the shell treats it as a recursive wildcard, and `find` already performs a recursive walk from `.`. Just use `-path './src/*'`.

Comment: @melpomene Okay, how do I make it not interpret the `*` literally, and treat it like the wildcard I intend?  The files *do* exist.

Comment: `rm` always interprets its arguments literally. `*` expansion is performed by the shell, but you're going straight from `sed` to `rm` here.

Comment: @melpomene That makes sense.  How can I do what I want to do in one fancy line of script?

Comment: Is `rm ./src/**/__tests__/*.js{,.map}` what you want? (Requires the `globstar` option to be enabled, of course).

Comment: Why not just do `find src -regex '.*/__tests__/[^/]*\.js\(\.map\)\?' -delete`? (Beware, untested.)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy perfect.  I have so much to learn about bash.  I'm born and raised Windows.  Write up your comment in an answer (and note the lack of expansion of *) and I'll mark it as the answer.  Also, could you explain why `rm $(...)` didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to explain the issue: In `find | sed | xargs rm`, the shell only sets up communication between those programs, but it doesn't actually process the results in any way. That's a problem here because `*.js` needs to be expanded *by a shell* to replace it with a list of filenames; `rm` treats every argument it's given as a literal name. (This is unlike Windows, where programs do their own command-line parsing and glob expansion).

Arguably, you don't need `find` here at all. Consider:

```
shopt -s globstar                 # enable ** as a recursion operator
rm ./src/**/__tests__/*.js{,.map} # delete *.js and *.js.map in any __tests__ directory under src
```

...or, if you *do* want to use `find`, let it do the work of coming up with a list of individual files matching `*.js`, instead of leaving that work to happen later:

```
find src -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/__tests__/[^/]*[.]js([.]map)?' -delete
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have your globs (`*`) expanded. File name expansion is performed by the shell on UNIX, not by `rm` or other programs. Try:

```
.... | xargs -d $'\n' sh -c 'IFS=; for f; do rm -- $f; done' sh
```

...to explain this:

- The `-d $'\n'` ensures that xargs splits only on newlines (not spaces!), and also stops it from treating backslashes and quotes as special.
- `sh -c '...' sh` runs `...` as a script, with `sh` as `$0`, and subsequent arguments in `$1`, etc; `for f;` will thus iterate over those arguments.
- Clearing `IFS` with `IFS=` prevents string-splitting from happening when `$f` is used unquoted, so only glob expansion happens.
- Using the `--` argument to `rm` ensures that it treats subsequent arguments as filenames, not options, even if they start with dashes.

That said, if you have really a lot of files for each pattern, you might run into an "argument list too long", even though you are using xargs.

---

Another caveat is that filenames containing newlines can potentially be split into multiple names (depending on the details of the version of `find` you're using). A way to solve this that will work with all POSIX-compliant versions of `find` might be:

```
find ./src -type d -name __tests__ -exec sh -c '
  for d; do
    rm -- "$d"/*.js{,.map}
  done
' sh {} +
```

Comment: `xargs sh -c rm` won't actually pass the arguments to `rm` at all. Subsequent arguments to `sh` become `$0`, `$1`, etc. in your script; but the script is just `rm`; it doesn't read `$0` or `$1` at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : You are right. I have updated my unser accordingly.

Comment: However, the new answer has serious security problems in the form of a shell injection vulnerability. If your codebase has a file called `hello-$(rm -rf ~).js`, you just lost your whole home directory.

Comment: This is correct. We implicitly do an `eval` here. IMO, the biggest problem is that the input to xargs is a glob pattern, and we need a shell to expand the globs, unless we want to take the detour via, say, a Perl, where we can apply solely `glob`. Actually, with `find`, your answer makes much more sense. My intention was to show how his original idea of can be modified to get the globs expanded.

Comment: You need a shell to expand globs, but you don't need eval to do it. Any unquoted parameter expansion will do globbing (when `set -f` isn't active). `xargs -d $'\n' sh -c 'IFS=; for item; do rm -- $item; done' _`, for example, should do the job safely.

Comment: The IFS-change is for coping with filenames which have spaces inside, right? But what is the lone underscore at the end (a typo?) and why do you set the input delimiter for xargs to a newline?

Comment: Correct, clearing IFS prevents string-splitting from happening on unquoted expansions, so the only remaining behavior is globbing. The underscore fills in `$0`, so other items become `$1` and onward, so `for item` iterates over them. I use the newline because the OP's `find | sed` pipeline emits one line per glob expression they want evaluated; whereas without either `-0` or `-d`, `xargs` does a bunch of parsing that basically makes it act like a slightly buggy shell (trying to honor quotes except when they're preceded by backslashes, etc).

Comment: That said, cutting over to use NUL delimiters (`find -print0`, `sed -z`, and `xargs -0`) would definitely be safer, insofar as that way you don't need to worry about a file created with, say, `d=$'src/evil/__tests__/\n/etc/paswd\n/' && mkdir -p "$d" && touch "$d/hi.js"` causing you to delete `/etc/passwd` if your installed version of `find`'s `-print` emits a literal newline when that's what a filename contains.

Comment: (Modern GNU `find` doesn't pass through a literal newline with `-print`, but it *will* with `-printf '%s\n'`; the POSIX spec doesn't define the behavior, so it can't be trusted that different versions will behave any consistent way -- whereas `-print0` isn't vulnerable to that class of issues, since NULs aren't valid in filenames anywhere in UNIX-land, as a consequence of NUL-delimited strings being used when passing names in and out of kernelspace, to/from the libc, etc).

Comment: Do you mind if I edit this answer to address the above-discussed vulnerability?